# Cannot enable administrator component

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to set the lock task packages but `IsAdminActive` is returning false.

To set the device owner and active admin I used the command `dpm set-device-owner PinningTest.PinningTest/.AdminReceiverTest` from the adb shell. This completed successfully.

My MainActivity:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)GetSystemService(Context.DevicePolicyService);
        ComponentName testDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AdminReceiverTest)).Name);

        if (devicePolicyManager.IsAdminActive(testDeviceAdmin))
        {
            devicePolicyManager.SetLockTaskPackages(testDeviceAdmin, new string[] { PackageName }); 
        }
    }
```

My AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="PinningTest.PinningTest" 
          android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" 
          android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
    <application android:label="PinningTest">
        <receiver android:name=".AdminReceiverTest" 
              android:label="@string/ApplicationName" 
              android:description="@string/ApplicationName" 
              android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

AdminReceiverTest.cs:

```
namespace PinningTest
{
    class AdminReceiverTest : DeviceAdminReceiver
    {
    }
}
```

I was following the tutorial [here](http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/) and have also looked at various others but I haven't been able to find a complete Xamarin example.

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Assuming your device is not rooted and there is no user account has been assigned (factory reset if you have to), after the `dpm` command, was `/data/system/device_owner.xml` updated? Also which device(?), as different manufacturers alter ASOP and they have special perms that have to be set, i.e. Samsung

Comment: Running `devicePolicyManager.IsDeviceOwnerApp(PackageName)` does return true but I get a permission denied if I try to open the file. I can see that it gets created after I run set-device-owner so I guess it is set correctly. It is a Lenovo tab3 on 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally had the same issue, but I've just got this working by using the following

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.sceneskope.survey.DeviceAdminReceiver", Enabled = true, Exported = true, Permission = "android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN")]
[MetaData("android.app.device_admin", Resource = "@xml/device_admin_receiver")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" })]
public class DeviceAdminReceiver : Android.App.Admin.DeviceAdminReceiver
{
}
```

And setting the device owner using

```
.\adb.exe shell dpm set-device-owner com.afwsamples.testdpc/.DeviceAdminReceiver
```

That appears to solve my problems, so I guess this was down to issues with the names when putting in the manifest manually.

Comment: Adding `[MetaData("android.app.device_admin", Resource = "@xml/device_admin")]` resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your manual manifest entries are not taking into account the auto-generated class names (Md5-based) that `Xamarin.Android` generates to avoid namespace collisions.

Since `DeviceAdminReceiver` is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`, use the `[BroadcastReceiver]` class attribute to override the auto-generated class names in your manifest:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.sushihangover.deviceownerapp.adminreceiver", Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" })]
public class AdminReceiverTest : DeviceAdminReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Thus in your manifest, the following is auto-generated:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.sushihangover.deviceownerapp.adminreceiver">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested the suggested changes and still had the same issue but it does sound like the class name could be the issue. With my code above `testDeviceAdmin.ClassName` is "md590431f01ea601a54308626715acc602b.AdminReceiverTest" and if I change it to `testDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AdminReceiverTest)).SimpleName);` then `testDeviceAdmin.ClassName` is "AdminReceiverTest". Neither are working though.

Comment: I get the following security exception if I run 'SetLockTaskPackages': No active admin ComponentInfo{PinningTest.PinningTest/md590431f01ea601a54308626715acc602b.AdminReceiverTest}.